# How to display multiple selected value in a box?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am making a form where when I select familyname of the product, its values will be display in a box (I don't know what I should use todisplay it) and the box can't be edited (only can be read).

-HTML

```
 <select name="fnme" onchange="setText(this)" multiple>
          <option value="STR12(12,YU,IO)">STR12(12,YU,IO)</option>
          <option value="STR13(13,YU,IO)">STR12(13,YU,IO)</option>
          <option value="STR14(14,YU,IO)">STR12(14,YU,IO)</option>
          <option value="STR15(15,YU,IO)">STR12(15,YU,IO)</option>
    </select>
<td><textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="textBox" id="disabled"  value=""/ disabled></textarea></td>
</br>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
```

-ASPCode

```
<%
DIM fnm,element        
fnm=Split(Request("fnme"),"\n")
FOR EACH element IN fnm
Response.Write("<p>--qq-- " & trim(element) & " </p>")
Next
%>
```

For now I'm using text area but still have a problem in displaying many value, it display on one selected value.

-JS

```
<script>
function setText(obj) {
var val = obj.value;
document.getElementById('textBox').value = val;
}
</script>
```

I want to know it is possible to display the multiple value?

Comment: Where is the texbox having the ID of `textBox`?

Comment: Just do this:  `document.getElementById('disabled').value += val;` and you are done!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak it works wahhh thankyou thankyou

Comment: `var val = obj.value;` will only get the first selected.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak but did you know if it can be display many value in one time cause it can work if it was selected one by one

Comment: @RobG can you show me how to get many value in one time?

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
var val = obj.value;
```

you're only going to get the value of the first selected option, not all of them (unless you're using something like jQuery).

And the forward slash in:

```
<textarea ... id="disabled"  value=""/ disabled>
```

doesn't help either. I'll assume that's just a posting typo.

```js
function getMultiSelectValue(select) {
  return [].reduce.call(select.options, function(values, option) {
    option.selected? values.push(option.value) : null;
    return values;
  }, []);
}

function showValues(values){
  document.getElementById('ta').value = values.join('\n');
}
```

```html
<select onchange="showValues(getMultiSelectValue(this))" multiple>
  <option value="0">0
  <option value="1">1
  <option value="2">2
</select>
<textarea id="ta" rows="3" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: I try this on IE , it didnt work but it works on chrome, thanks for this I learn something new like calling two function at once. I'm still trying to find how to work on IE, Thank you :D

Comment: Which version of IE doesn't it work on? I know IE 8 didn't like host objects being passed to built-in Array methods as *this*, but it should have a [*polyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) so that shouldn't be an issue. I'd expect this to work in IE 9+ (but I can't test that for a while).

Comment: I'm using IE 11 version, I will try to learn polyfill, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you.

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="" name="tof">
<select name="fnme" onchange="setText(this)" multiple>
          <option value="STR12(12,YU,IO)">STR12(12,YU,IO)</option>
          <option value="STR13(13,YU,IO)">STR12(13,YU,IO)</option>
          <option value="STR14(14,YU,IO)">STR12(14,YU,IO)</option>
          <option value="STR15(15,YU,IO)">STR12(15,YU,IO)</option>
</select>
<textarea id="res" readOnly></textarea>
</form> 

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function setText(ob){
    var selected_options = document.forms['tof']['fnme'].selectedOptions
    var selected_options_values = []
    for(i=0; i<selected_options.length; i++){
     selected_options_values.push(selected_options[i].value)
    }
 document.getElementById('res').value = selected_options_values.join('\n')
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't works with IE11 but work on google chrome :) I'm searching for where we can use on IE11